# icinga2 mysql connection issue

Tags: mysql, socket, icinga

I followed all the install wizards When setting up icinga2, I have the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)
```

I tried using the mysql command line utility, and I got the same response. To fix this, I symlinked the socket such that `ls -alF` shows the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 25 Jun  2 10:23 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock -> /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock=
```

and `ls -alF /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` returns

```
srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0 Jun  2 10:39 /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock=
```

Now the mysql command line works without complaint, but I continue to receive "Can't connect" errors from the icinga2 web interface. I cannot find anywhere in the logs that shows any errors. I've checked the following log files:

```
ido2db.debug (does some stuff and then cleans up child processes)
apache2/error.log (nothing)
apache2/access.log (shows requests coming through from web interface)
icinga2.err (nothing)
icinga2/startup.log (looks pretty standard)
```

There do not appear to be any logs that are specific to the icinga2 web interface (there's no /var/log/icingaweb2, and there's no web log in /var/log/icinga2)

I do not want to change the mycnf file because I have many other services relying on the current location of the mysql socket.

How do I solve this problem? I can't seem to find a config that I can modify for icinga2 to point it at a different socket. Can I set up mysql to have 2 sockets?

If I change the my.cnf file to set the socket in the correct location, everything works.

Answer (score 0):

The directory `/var/lib/mysql` is usually only readable my the users mysql and of course root.

So any other user, like nagios, icinga or Apache's system user won't be able to access the socket.

Comment: But it works when I change the location of the socket in my.cnf, and that socket is also owned by mysql?

Comment: What OS is that?

Comment: I'm running this on Ubuntu 14.04